# Second check in or-statement not executed

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

In my php application i do the following check:

```
    if(($images = $main->get_images($data['id'])) || ($videos = $main->get_videos($data['id']))){
           (...)
        if($videos){
           (...)    
        }


        if($images){
           (...)
        }
    }
```

This operation sends back an error saying $videos is undefined. My guess is that if the first statement is true, the second wont be checked. Is there any neat way of preforming the second check, even is the first one is true, because in this case if images is true, videos will be evaluated as false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way.  You'll need to re-write it into something like this...

```
$images = $main->get_images($data['id']);
$videos = $main->get_videos($data['id']);
if($images || $videos){
       (...)
    if($videos){
       (...)    
    }
    if($images){
       (...)
    }
}
```

And just FYI...  order of operations means you don't need to enclose the conditions in () brackets.  Almost everything gets computed BEFORE the OR operator (including the && operator).

Good luck!

Joey

Comment: Thank you! I feel so stupid now... (you forgot a ; in the 2nd line, but i cant change it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `empty()` to see if a variable does not exist or is null e.g.

```
if(!empty($videos)) {
       (...)    
}
```